# Missing NSMicrophoneUsageDescription warning on app submission

Tags: ios, dji-sdk

I'm seeing new App Store warnings with DJISDK 4.8.2 now requiring `NSMicrophoneUsageDescription`. [Github issue #163](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-SDK-iOS/issues/163) said DJIs convenience class was removed in 4.4. Is this not true anymore?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with *DJI-SDK-iOS* version ver 4.8.2. When submitting the app to iTunesConnect, I received a letter from Apple:

> We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, "app name". Please  correct the following issues, then upload again.
>
> Missing Purpose String in Info.plist File - Your app's code references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's Info.plist file should contain a NSMicrophoneUsageDescription key with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your app needs the data. Starting Spring 2019, all apps submitted to the App Store that access user data will be required to include a purpose string.If you're using external libraries or SDKs, they may reference APIs that require a purpose string. While your app might not use these APIs, a purpose string is still required. You can contact the developer of the library or SDK and request they release a version of their code that doesn't contain the APIs. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/protecting_the_user_s_privacy).